# API built in express responds with empty array

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have my application populating an array with names. I can log the array values and it is getting the values, but using postman to make a request on `localhost:8888/api/messages` my response says `matches : []` with the empty array. Why is my array empty in the response if I do indeed populate it?

```
router.get('/messages', function(request, res) {

  var names = [];
  ctxioClient.accounts(ID).contacts().get({limit:250, sort_by: "count", sort_order: "desc"}, 
    function ( err, response) {
      if(err) throw err;

      console.log("getting responses...");
      var contacts = response.body;
      var matches = contacts.matches;


      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
        names.push(matches[i].name);
        matches[i].email;
      }  

    res.json({matches : names});   
  });


});
```

Comment: async, async, async.  All async results must be processed and used inside the async completion callback, not outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `response.json()` executes before the `ctxioclient.get()` happens. Call response.json inside .get() instead. Something like this

```
router.get('/messages', function(request, response) { // <--- router response
  var names = [];
  ctxioClient.accounts(ID).contacts().get({ limit: 250,sort_by: "count",sort_order: "desc"},function(err, resp) { // <---- using resp
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("getting responses...");
      var contacts = response.body; 
      var matches = contacts.matches;
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        names.push(matches[i].name);
        matches[i].email;
      }
      response.json({ matches: names }); // <--- router response
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm putting it where you stated, but I then get the error `response.json has no method json`

Comment: the function inside .get also have the variable response. I just saw that. rename it to something else

Comment: Ok actually i'm assuming this is because I pass two parameters in as `response` and it is trying with the ctxClient response and not the get reponse

Comment: yes, true. Please check my updated answer. You'll see that the callback function for ctxioclient.get will have a parameter `resp` instead of `response`

Comment: I fixed it, and now I get no error, but my array is still empty. I've updated my code to reflect my changes

Comment: try doing a console.log before response.json and see if the result is not empty

Comment: I restarted my server, and did the console.log(resp.json) and it prints a bunch of stuff in json format, but also gives me a `can't set headers after they are sent` error

Comment: just do a `console.log(names);` see if that is displaying correct

Comment: Works now! It involved restarting the server. +1 and accepted answer for you.